# How to tell if a series diverges or is indeterminate? Study of some cases of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty3^n (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}k^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a series dependent on a parameter. For example:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty3^n (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}k^n.$$

By root test, we know that this series *absolutely* converges (hence converges) if  $|k|<(3e)^{-1}$ *absolutely* diverges if $|k|>(3e)^{-1}$.

> Now how do I tell what the series does if $|k|\geq(3e)^{-1}$?

This is my work:

I have been able to work out that for $k = (3k)^{-1}$, $$3^n (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}k^n$$ does not go to zero and then the series diverges positively (since it has positive terms).

> For $- k = (3e)^{-1}$, $$3^n (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}k^n$$ does not go to
>   zero either, but in this case what can I say?

In addition, I can tell that for $k>(3e)^{-1}$ the series diverges since it has positive terms.

> But what can I say if $k<(3e)^{-1}$?

More in general: what can I say if a series absolutely diverges and doesn't have positive (or negatives) terms only?

Comment: Try the Alternating Series Test. There will be a $(-1)^n$ factor, so if you can show that the $a_n$ is positive, approaches 0 as $n$ approaches $\infty$, and that $a_n$ decreases, then that series converges conditionally, since the absolute value of the series diverges for $k = -(3e)^{-1}$

Comment: @user62029: I think you complicated a little. Immediately by the root test, for $|k| < (3e)^{-1}$ the series converges and for $|k| > (3e)^{-1}$ the series diverges. So the hard part is for $k = \pm (3e)^{-1},$ which you partially solved.

Comment: @Adayah: no, if $|k|>(3e)^{-1}$, all I can say is that it *does not converge*: we don't know if it is divergent or indeterminate.

Comment: I was assuming the softer definition: a series is divergent when it does not converge. Now I understand you want to distinguish between the limit being $\infty$ and non-existent.

Comment: @Adayah Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, the root test is inconclusive when $|k| = (3e)^{-1}$. So that means we need to check both cases separately. As you have shown in your result, when $k = (3e)^{-1}$, the series diverges. However, when $k = -(3e)^{-1}$, the series mentioned before with an extra factor of $(-1)^n$. However, the limit of this new $a_n \neq 0$, so the series diverges for $k = -(3e)^{-1}$ as well. Therefore, you can say that the series converges absolutely for $k \in (-(3e)^{-1}, (3e)^{-1})$ and diverges on the rest of the domain.

Comment: If $|k|>(3e)^{-1}$, all I can say is that it *does not converge*: we don't know if it is divergent or indeterminate. My question is how can I tell that too? Also, you have shown that it does not converge for $|k|= - (3e)^{-1}$, but you didn't say if it diverges or is indeterminate.

Comment: Remember one of the first things in the series course is the test for divergence: if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$, then the series diverges? As you said in the question, that is the case for $k = (3e)^{-1}$, so adding a $(-1)^n$ factor just makes it oscillate.

Comment: SalmonKiller: If that limit isn't equal to zero, you can conclude that the series does not converge. Divergence is given if the series has only positive (or negative) terms. Yes, I see now that is oscillates for $k = -(3e)^{-1}$. It now leaves only the case $k < -(3e)^{-1}$. I guess that also in this case the series oscillates (that is, it is indeterminate). How can I prove it?

Comment: @user62029 For that case you have already shown divergence with the root test.

Comment: I don't think so. I have shown absolute divergence (that is, divergence of the series of the absolute values).

Comment: @user62029 I don't think there is a concept called absolute divergence. There is conditional convergence, but there is only one type of divergence. Right?

Comment: Since $a_n$ in fact has no limit but oscillates between two values that approach $\pm 1$ in the limit, it might be an interesting exercise to consider what happens if we instead examine the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[(3k)^{2n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{(2n)^2}+(3k)^{2n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)^{(2n-1)^2}\right]$ when $k = -1/(3e)$.  Does that sum converge?

Comment: @BrianTung Is that the sum of the series with the two different values of $k$?

Comment: @SalmonKiller: I've just expanded $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{2n}+a_{2n-1})$, so that the oscillating terms (mostly) cancel out.  Does that sum converge?  If so, what to?

Comment: SalmonKiller: Here are some of the definitions that I'm using. I define that a series diverges if its sum is $\infty$. If the sum of the absolute values diverges or converges, I say that the series absolutely diverges/converges. A theorem is that a absolute convergence implies convergence. Also, if the sum doesn't exist, I say that the series is indeterminate.

Comment: @user62029 If the absolute value diverges, but the actual series converges, that is called conditional convergence. Using your terms, we have shown absolute divergence, however we can also show both types of divergences using the test for divergence. Right?

Comment: @user62029: That seems like an odd use of the phrases "absolutely diverges" and "indeterminate".  I think common usage would phrase what you intend as "fails to absolutely converge" and "diverges".  However, taking your terms as you have used them: The fact that the terms fail to have a limit at $0$ as $n \to \infty$ when $k < -(3e)^{-1}$ is sufficient to show that the sum is indeterminate (i.e., diverges), since one cannot find an $N$ beyond which the partial sums are all within some $\varepsilon$-neighborhood.

Comment: Nope. OP wants to distinguish between three cases: the series converges, diverges to $\pm \infty$ or has no sum at all. If the terms fail to converge to $0$ it still does not imply whether it is divergent or indeterminate.

Comment: @Adayah if it has no sum, doesn't that mean it diverges?

Comment: According to the terminology I am also used to - yes. But not to the OP's. $\pm \infty$ = divergent, no sum = indeterminate.